# Symfony 2.6.8 + Doctrine 2.5.* incorrect json_array type persist/decode

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I try to persist json_array type

```
   /**
     * @var array
     * @ORM\Column(type="json_array", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $sizes;
```

as usual

```
$obj = new Object();
...
$obj->setSizes($sizes);
...
$em->persist($obj);
$em->flush();
```

, Doctrine saves simple array (list)

```
array(3, 4, 5, 6)
```

as such string:

```
[[["3","4","5","6"]]]
```

(multilevel-like array)

The problem is when I try to get this data back it is also the miltilevel array

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => string '3' (length=1)
          1 => string '4' (length=1)
          2 => string '5' (length=1)
          3 => string '6' (length=1)
```

and I can not iterate it normally as it was before (Doctrine 2.4.*), i.e. in Twig

```
{% for size in entity.sizes %}
  {{ size }}
{% endfor %}
```

Am I doing something wrong, when persisting and getting back such data or there is a bug in Doctrine 2.5.* ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I' ve found bug in my code, lol. (student)

the problem was in my setter

```
/**
 * Add sizes
 * @param $sizes
 * @return SupplierProduct
 */
public function setSizes($sizes = array())
{
    $this->sizes[] = $sizes;

    return $this;
}
```

not

```
$this->sizes[]
```

but

```
$this->sizes
```